# create a new sheet with a respective column name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where column B is employee code I need to create a new sheet whenever a new employee code is seen and append the respective row to the new sheet corresponding to the employee code and delete the respective row in the master sheet. whenever the same employee code comes I need to append row to the respective employee code sheet. eg emp code 10003810 is seen three times in this sheet for the first 10003810 i create a sheet with name 10003810 and append the row to this sheet and whenever 10003810 come , i append the respective to the sheet 10003810.
The code I tried is

```
   function sheetCreate(){
   var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet1 = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1")
   var getNames = sheet1.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
   var erg = sheet1.getDataRange();                                                
   var evA=erg.getValues();                                                   
   var d=0;

   for (var i =1;i<=getNames.length; i++) {
      var copy = getNames[i];
      var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
      newSheet.setName(copy);
      newSheet.appendRow(copy);
      sheet1.deleteRow(i+1-d);
      d++;                                                                   
     }     
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to use the column "B" of the sheet "Form Responses 1".
- When the value of the column "B" is not existing in the sheet names in the Spreadsheet, you want to insert new sheet with the name of the value.
- When the value of the column "B" is existing in the sheet names in the Spreadsheet, you want to append the value to the same sheet name with the value.
- You want to delete all rows in the sheet "Form Responses 1" after above process was finished.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the new sheet is created for all values. And when the value is the empty, an error occurs.
- I think that in your case, how about using `clearContent()` and/or `clear()` instead of `deleteRow`?

  - About this, I would like to propose 2 modification patterns.

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, the rows are deleted like your script.

```
function sheetCreate(){
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var [, ...getNames] = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();  // <--- Modified
  var erg = sheet1.getDataRange();
  var evA=erg.getValues();
  
  // And, I modified below script.
  // 1. Create an object including the sheet name and sheet object.
  var sheetsObj = activeSpreadsheet.getSheets().reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e.getSheetName()]: e}), {});
  
  // 2. Insert new sheet and copy the values to the sheet, and return the last row of the column "B".
  // <--- Modified
  var deleteRows = getNames.reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    if (r[1].toString() != "") {
      if (r[1] in sheetsObj) {
        sheetsObj[r[1]].appendRow(r);
      } else {
        var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet(r[1].toString());
        newSheet.appendRow(r);
        sheetsObj[r[1]] = newSheet;
      }
      ar.push(i + 2);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []).pop();
  
  // 3. Delete rows.
  sheet1.deleteRows(2, deleteRows - 1);
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, the rows are cleared. In this case, please modify above script as follows.

From:

```
sheet1.deleteRows(2, deleteRows - 1);
```

To:

```
sheet1.getRange(2, 1, deleteRows - 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).clearContent();  // Or clear()
```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [insertSheet(sheetName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname)
- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)
- [clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear)

### Added:

From your request of `if possible can you help me out this code with if or loop conditions`, I modified above script as follows. The result of the script is the same for both scripts.

#### Modified script:

```
function sheetCreate2(){
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var getNames = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  getNames.shift();
  var erg = sheet1.getDataRange();
  var evA=erg.getValues();
  
  var sheets = activeSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  var sheetsObj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetsObj[sheets[i].getSheetName()] = sheets[i];
  }
  var deleteRows = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
    var r = getNames[i];
    if (r[1].toString() != "") {
      if (r[1] in sheetsObj) {
        sheetsObj[r[1]].appendRow(r);
      } else {
        var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet(r[1].toString());
        newSheet.appendRow(r);
        sheetsObj[r[1]] = newSheet;
      }
      deleteRows = i + 2;
    }    
  }
  
  sheet1.deleteRows(2, deleteRows - 1);
}
```

Comment: Program works fine actually i don't want the value only to be appended, I want the whole row to be appended. what you have mentioned in point no  is value only to be appended

Comment: @Kumara Guru Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Thanks alot, The program works fine.As I am new to appscript I am unable to understand the code as this is a bit complicated even if want to modify this program I do't Know where to modify( I didn't understand from object declaration)

Comment: if possible can you help me out this code with if or loop conditions

Comment: @Kumara Guru Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience, again. From your replying, I could understand that my sample script could resolve your question. About `if possible can you help me out this code with if or loop conditions`, in my sample script, the if statement and loop are used. So although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your new request, I added one more sample script which works the same action with above sample script using the for loop. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.